# "Invalid operation" error in resizeGL after window closed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

- Window 10 64-bit
- Python 3.8
- PyQt 6.3.0
- PySide 6.3.1
- PyOpenGL 3.1.6

When I close the window, I get an "Invalid operation" error in resizeGL() on the line with the glViewport() function. This happens with PyQt6 and PySide6.

```py
import sys

from OpenGL.GL import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtOpenGL import QOpenGLWindow
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication


class OpenGLWindow(QOpenGLWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initializeGL(self):
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.ApplicationAttribute.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = OpenGLWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Debugging details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\_Projects\OpenGL\basic-examples\animations\set-swap-interval-opengl21-pyqt6-python\opengl_window.py", line 15, in resizeGL
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 230, in glCheckError
    raise self._errorClass(
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1282,
        description = b'invalid operation',
        baseOperation = glViewport,
        cArguments = (0, 0, 160, 160)
)
```

Comment: You need to provide debugging details. It works fine on my Ubuntu PC. Anyway why not report a bug? See [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Reporting_Bugs).

Comment: I added debugging details.

Comment: I upgraded from PyQt 6.3.0 to PyQt 6.4.2 but that didn't fix the issue. I'll try to report a bug.

Comment: I reported the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-111016